# Insert timestamp type data into Oracle database through codeignier

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, insert, timestamp

I am trying to insert a row into Oracle though Codeigniter Active record. Basically I am getting an error for created_date column whose datatype is timestamp.
My code is like

```
$data['CREATED_DATE']   = getDatetimeforDB();
$this->db->insert("MY_TABLE_NAME", $data);

function getDatetimeforDB() {
    
    return date("j-M-y h.i.s.u A");
}
```

But after executing the code, I am getting datetime error :

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string - Invalid query: INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE_NAME" ("ACTIVITY", "ACTIVITY_LOG", "CREATED_DATE", "USER_ID") VALUES ('users/logout', '"Logout"', '10-Aug-20 12.46.02.000000 PM', '555')
```

Please let me know what may be the issue. If I run the query directly through sql query, it is working fine, but not working through codeigniter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Answer (score 0):

Used this PHP `date()` function as `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

```
$data['CREATED_DATE']   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$this->db->insert("MY_TABLE_NAME", $data);
```

Comment: Thanks for yout reply. But nope! I have tried this also. Actually while I am trying to fetch the array's element datatype, I am getting string instead of datetime.